# How to allow nullable generic type in C# 8 as a return type for a method?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable-reference-types

I have the following code:

```
public async Task<T> Retrieve<T>()
    where T : class, ITableEntity
{
    var result = await GetData<T>();
    return result.Result as T; // result.Result is object
}
```

Now the compiler gives a warning `Possible null reference return`. I can fix it with '!', but I actually do want to allow null, so it seems wrong to do it this way. I don't really know why does a compiler assume that class means non-nullable, I tried to write `class?` (don't even know what that means, but it compiles, though it gives the same warning).

Is it possible to tell compiler that T can be a nullable reference type? I guess it defaults to non-nullable.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Task<T?>` as return type then, if you want `T` to be nullable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```cs
public async Task<T?> Retrieve<T>()
    where T : class, ITableEntity
```

Comment: Won't that mean though that T in itself is non-nullable meaning there will be warnings if I pass it to a wrong context? Seems a bit strange that I have a T that is already nullable, but then we do T? adding "one more nullable"

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik but that's the entire point of C# 8 nullability; `T` **is not** nullable, even if `T` is known to be a reference-type. `T?` is nullable. For example, with `System.String` (a class): `string` is **non-nullable**, `string?` is nullable.

Comment: @MarcGravell For some reason this does not work for generic type parameter on the class level: `RepositoryBase<T> where T : BaseEntity` and for method `Task<T?> GetAsync(...)` I get error: `A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type. Consider adding a 'class', 'struct', or type constraint.`

Comment: @PavelVoronin that sounds like you don't have reference nullability enabled at either the project or class level; example here: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4CsA3IQPR0DEAdgK4A27AhsOzKTGY8+hbKQBCXAM4wAoswAuASwUBPUgG8AvqKykASjAAOEKSuirJMgDwAVAHykA7gAsYsUrdIgJ0uYpVVQg1CUjDyJDsAfkcAcRgFAEEpVWYwAAoASlIAXkcFFygIJ1JmGBKAOQgFAEkAWyM+OsEFGAATWQQwY2UIZizaAi0gA= - uncomment the `#nullable enable` and it works fine (note: you should ideally do this in the csproj, not via `#nullable`)

Comment: Yep, just found out this.I had to add `notnull`: `RepositoryBase<T> where T : notnull, BaseEntity`